# Squared Prediction Error and PCA derivation

Tags: pca

I've been looking at the Squared Prediction Error for PCA. It is defined as follows:

$$Q = rr^\text{T}$$

Where

$$r = x(I- PP^\text{T})$$

Now it is claimed that

$$Q = x(I- PP^\text{T})x^\text{T}$$

But I cannot see how? My reasoning is as follows:

$$Q = rr^\text{T} \\
 = x(I- PP^\text{T}) (x(I- PP^\text{T}))^\text{T} \\
 = x(I- PP^\text{T})(I- PP^\text{T})^\text{T} x^\text{T}$$

Now $(A+B)^\text{T} = A^\text{T} + B^\text{T}$ and $(AB)^\text{T} = B^\text{T}A^\text{T} $, hence

$$(I- PP^\text{T})^\text{T}\\
= I^\text{T}- (PP^\text{T})^\text{T} \\
= I^\text{T}- PP^\text{T} \\$$

Therefore we find that

$$Q = x(I- PP^\text{T})(I- PP^\text{T})x^\text{T}$$

Now clearly this is not equal to

$$Q = x(I- PP^\text{T})x^\text{T}$$

unless some further assumptions are invoked? For example $(I- PP^\text{T})(I- PP^\text{T})$ can be expanded to give

$$(I- PP^\text{T})(I- PP^\text{T}) \\
 = II -2PP^\text{T} +PP^\text{T}PP^\text{T} \\
 = I -2PP^\text{T} +PP^\text{T}PP^\text{T} \\
$$
If $P^\text{T}P = I$ then this would reduce to $I - PP^\text{T}$. But if $P^\text{T}P = I$ then surely $PP^\text{T} = I$ in which case

$$Q = x(I- PP^\text{T})x^\text{T} = 0 \:\: \forall \:\: x$$

And hence $PP^\text{T} \neq I$, $P^\text{T}P \neq I$ and $Q \neq x(I- PP^\text{T})x^\text{T}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes :-) If $P^\top P=I$ then it does  **not** follow that $PP^\top = I$, so your "surely" is wrong. $P$ is not square.

Comment: Hi Amoeba, Ah yes of course P is not square that's a very good point. So it is true that $P^\text{T}P = I$? i.e. so the "proof", as poor as it is, is correct? And agreed then that $PP^\text{T}\neq I$. I can't find a good reference on this, it must be burred in a graduate text somewhere. In addition if P is square, i.e. it contains all the eigen-vectors of the eigen-matrix V, then we know that $VV^\text{T}= I$ and that would imply that $Q=0 \forall x$?

Comment: Yes it is true that $P^\top P=I$ because $P$ contains covariance matrix  eigenvectors as columns, and they are all orthogonal and have unit length. And yes, if you use all eigenvectors, then you do not reduce dimensionality at all and so reconstruction error is zero.

Comment: If this is clear to you by now, feel free to post an answer yourself, if you want!

Answer (score 2):

Apologize for not explaining well previously

Let $z_n\in\mathbb{R}^{M}$ be the hidden/latent variables obtained by projecting the observed variables as the following,

\begin{equation}
z_n = P^Tx_n
\end{equation}
where $x_n\in\mathbb{R}^D$ is a vector of observed variables and $P\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times M}$ is of $M$ orthonormal eigenvectors of the covariance of $x_n$.

The optimal reconstruction of $x_n$ from $z_n$ in the least squares sense is given by,

\begin{equation}
\hat{x}_n = Pz_n
\end{equation}
where $\hat{x}_n$ is the reconstructed observation.

If you replace $z_n$ in the above equation, you will get $\hat{x}_n$ in terms of the original observation as the following,

\begin{equation}
\hat{x}_n = PP^Tx_n
\end{equation}

The reconstruction residuals are given by,
\begin{equation}
r_n = x_n - \hat{x}_n = x_n - PP^Tx_n = (I - PP^T)x_n
\end{equation}
where $r_n$ are the reconstruction residuals or errors.

Therefore, SPE should be expressed as,

\begin{equation}
SPE = Q = r_n^Tr_n =  x_n^T(I - PP^T)^T(I - PP^T)x_n
\end{equation}

Further, as $(I - PP^T)^T$ is symmetric, we can rewrite the above equation as, 
\begin{equation}
Q =  x_n^T(I - PP^T)(I - PP^T)x_n
\end{equation}

and eventually as,
\begin{equation}
Q =  x_n^T(I - PP^T - PP^T + PP^TPP^T)x_n
\end{equation}

where, $P^TP = I$ as $P$ is an orthonormal matrix, which allows further simplification of the following form,

\begin{equation}
Q =  x_n^T(I - PP^T)x_n
\end{equation}

You would probably have figured this out. Hopefully, this helps others!

Comment: I am not clear how you see this as moving things forward. Can you expand it into a full answer?

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.